# FullCalendar, events are not refreshed

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, fullcalendar

Here is my jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#refresh').on('click', function(){
    var json_events;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxRefresh.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'type=fetch',
        success: function(response){
            json_events = response;
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: json_events
    });
})
</script>
```

All is OK in fact, except thaat the calendar is not updated when I click on the button.

I did a console.log in order to see if my JSON returned by ajax was OK. And I got :

```
[{"id":"10","title":"Rugby","start":"2017-05-16T00:01:00+05:30","end":"2017-05-19T00:01:00+05:30","allDay":false}]
```

Thanks in advance for your precious help.

PS : I included 'fr.js' because I need my calendar to be in french.

Comment: I tried to use he option : async: false. But I have this in the console : "jquery.min.js:4 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/."

Comment: No no, put `$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ events: json_events });` **AFTER** `console.log(response);` (i.e - Inside the ajax success callback)

Comment: I tried. But the calendar is sadly not refreshed...                         
success: function(response){
                json_events = response;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    events: json_events
                });
                console.log(response);
            }

Comment: I posted an answer, please check it out (My flag was probably wrong so I removed it)

Comment: As for the error you get in the comment - Make sure you added `<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>` before you load `fullcalendar.js` in your page (Not sure if that's the reason)

Comment: @Kuartz have you tried my approach? See answer below. The accepted answer seems not to be actually related to the problem?

Comment: I am sorry. I accepted the wrong answer. I missed click... Your solution helped me. I used the "event : " option of fullcalendar to get datas. And it worked well. As you said, each time I want to refresh datas, I just need to refetch events. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @kuartz no problem, happy to help. Was the solution sufficient to consider awarding the open bounty as well?

Comment: It is. How can I give you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your approach the wrong way round really. This should work better:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) { 
      $.ajax({
        url: 'ajaxRefresh.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'type=fetch',
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
            callback(response); //sends the events to fullCalendar
        }
      });
    }
});

$('#refresh').on('click', function(){
  $("#calendar").refetchEvents();
});
```

This defines an event source for the calendar using the built-in architecture of fullCalendar. It will automatically re-runs this whenever the calendar view and/or date range is changed. Note though that really your PHP should be accepted the "start" and "end" parameters and only returning data for the dates that are currently being displayed on the calendar. That way you don't download more data than you actually need, which will improve performance, especially if you app runs for many years and collects lots of data, most of which users won't view any more after a certain point.

And then, when you click "refresh", it runs the "refetchEvents" method manually, which just causes that same function you supplied to the "events" parameter again as an extra call.

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/ for more details.

It might also be worth looking at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/ - if you can make your PHP page comply with the structure required by this, you can simplify things and remove the "ajax" call entirely from the client-side code, and just write `events: "ajaxRefresh.php" as the events property in fullCalendar.

Answer (score 1):

the time is not a valid javascript datetime. you need to convert the start and end to javascript datetime

example :-

`var d = new Date("2015-03-25T12:00:00-06:30");`

Comment: How could I do this in my code? It is AJAX + callback with datas coming from PHP file. So how should I be able to convert parts of data returned into date?

Comment: It's hard to see how this is related to the question? Where would you place this code, and how does it help with the fact that the event data is not refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

My modified code for your problem,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#refresh').on('click', function(){
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajaxRefresh.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'type=fetch',
    success: function (data) {
                var events = [];
                var myCalendar = $('#calendar');
                myCalendar.fullCalendar();
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');  //reset existing data in calendar
                $.each(data.d, function (index, value) {
                    events.push({
                        id: value.id,
                        title: value.title,
                        start: FormatDate(value.start),
                        end: FormatDate(value.end),
                        allDay: value.allDay, 
                        color: '#1C84C6',
                    });
                    myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', events[index]); //inserts the event into calendar plugin
                });
            }
   });
})

 function FormatDate(data) {
        var pattern = /Date\(([^)]+)\)/;
        var results = pattern.exec(data);
        return new Date(parseFloat(results[1]));
    }
</script>
```